# Кнопки при генерации карточек JS AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Задача **сгенерировать карточки** с информацией, полученной из API. На самих карточках должны присутствовать кнопки, например для записи информации в БД (и прочие манипуляции с БД). Работу с базой будет осуществлять php скрипт.
**Суть вопроса заключается в том, как это реализовать правильно, чтобы обработчиком кнопок выступал php скрипт?** У меня есть вариант обернуть кнопки в тег  и в ссылке указать переход на php скрипт и потом быстрый редирект обратно. Или все же засунуть на карточку форму?
Буду так же рад услышать от вас советы по поводу общей реализации задуманного.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тут делал ajax. На каждую кнопочку навесить class или idшник, и уже в js по клику на кнопку определять на какой action ajax будет обрабатывать информацию. Про [аякс тут можно почитать](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494)

Comment: Благодарю, направили в правильном направлении.